# question about array to DTO with spatie library

Tags: php, laravel

i was playing around with spatie dto library and i found myself with a problem.

how do i cast an array to a subobject?

```
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObject;

class OtherDTOCollection extends DataTransferObject {
    public OtherDto $collection;
}

class OtherDTO extends DataTransferObject {
    public int $id;
    public string $test;
}

class MyDTO extends DataTransferObject {
    public OtherDTO $collection;
}

class MyDTO2 extends DataTransferObject {
    public OtherDTOCollection $collection;
}
// WORKS
$MyDTO = new MyDTO(
    collection: [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'test' => 'test'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'test' => 'test'
        ]
    ]
);

// DOESN'T WORK
$MyDTO2 = new MyDTO2(
    collection: [
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'test' => 'test'
        ],
        [
            'id' => 1,
            'test' => 'test'
        ]
    ]
);
```

here's the relevant code, how can i make it work so that i have an array of objects?

thanks

Comment: use `new XXXX` to declare a new object

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the CastWith class form Spatie Attributes. .

use Spatie\DataTransferObject\Casters\ArrayCaster;
use Spatie\DataTransferObject\Attributes\CastWith;

Comment: thanks, i tried but i can't really make it work, do you have, by chance, a working example of it working?
maybe on my example? it would be really great!
thanks in advance :)

Comment: This could help check it out https://github.com/spatie/data-transfer-object

Answer (score 0):

This example will give you array of dto objects. `/** @var \DTO\PrefixListItem[] */` comment has key role, type here full namespace, not on the top with `use`

```
namespace \DTO;

use Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObject;

class PrefixListResult extends DataTransferObject
{
    /** @var \DTO\PrefixListItem[] */
    public ?array $list = [];
    public ?string $server_time = null;

    public ?int $code = null;
    public ?string $message = null;
    public ?array $details = [];
}



namespace \DTO;

use Spatie\DataTransferObject\DataTransferObject;

class PrefixListItem extends DataTransferObject
{
    public string $imsi_prefix;
    public string $operator;
    public int $min_sim_active_days;
    public int $max_sim_active_days;
    public bool $call_forwarding;
}
```